# Sql-server: update all rows columns based on IP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table LogPixelCall(example of two rows):

```
1   d5104006-8a82-4dfe-b6ca-587d25e869e9    1   2   2016-03-07 16:31:41.997 **92.26.242.166**   NULL    
2   5a5ffea2-3a70-4138-aeb7-4dd94900ef27    1   2   2016-03-07 17:39:57.557 **185.28.19.174**   NULL
```

where bolded is IP, and last NULL field is CountryId from other table.

Now I have Iplookup table, where I have to pass converted IP to long(so I have to use that conversion algorithm) and it returns me CountryCode (GB, US, AU), then I compare CountryCode with Country table, where I store countries. I want to then update LogPixelCall information table manually with CountryId, because this was missing before.

Question: Based on provided database schema, how do I update LogPixelCall CountryId NULL field, if I know ClientIp in LogPixelCall, and I can use IpLookup to get CountryIsoCode and connect with Country?

Comment: What is your question?  Do you have sample code?

Comment: What type of database? A SQL to update a table from another table can be slightly different depending on the database type/version.

Comment: I fell your question lack some clarification so I cannot really answer. But your query can look something like "update lpc
set lpc.ContryId = ct.Id
from LogPixelCall lpc
join IpLookUp il on il.[From] = IpConvertFunction(lpc.ClientIP)
join Country ct on ct.code = il.ContryIsoCode
where lpc.ContryId is null"

Comment: Database type is MSSQL

Comment: UPDATE LogPixelCall SET CountryId = Country.Id FROM LogPixelCall 
  INNER JOIN IpLookup
  ON IpLookup.CommonField = LogPixelCall.[Common Field] INNER JOIN Country ON Country.CommonField = IpLookup.CommonField
  WHERE LogPixelCall.CountryId IS NULL;

Answer (score 0):

```
update LogPixelCall set CountryId = c.Id
--select * /*Check first to make sure */
from LogPixelCall lpc
inner join IpLookup ip on lpc.ClientIp between ip.From and ip.To
inner join Country c on c.Code = ip.CountryIsoCode
```